# regular expression domain address

Tags: regex

i am using this regular expression and it works fine for the two dots which accepts abc.com.ae or abc.com , but i want to make it work for three dots like abc.abc.com.ae or abc.com.ae or abc.com (the first portion and the last portion is optional . how can i do that?`

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}\.[a-z]{3}((\.)[a-z]{2})?$
```

Comment: What is your goal? Validate that a given string is a valid domain name or parse it and extract portions of it?

Comment: Domain names are nowadays not only made up of ASCII characters.

Comment: interesting tags for that question ;)

Comment: Google "domain name regex" to find an expression that matches any domain. But it may not be the answer you are expecting, considering the tags, as said JH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}\.)+[a-z]{3}((\.)[a-z]{2})?$
```

i hope th is makes you happy, whatever you are trying to accomplish...